# Google showing an old logo even though I've added the new logo in the JSON-LD

Tags: seo

My site has a logo in .svg format:

[image]

*Image: The new logo (svg)*

The client has requested for the old logo also to be present for a while. That one is a .png. Now Google has indexed that old logo as the main logo:

[image]

*Image: Google result showing the old logo.*

What I want:

- Disable the old logo from search results
- Make sure the new logo is shown as the main logo

## Disable the old logo from search restults

For disabling the old logo I've made a change in the Robots.txt file:

```
Sitemap: https://www.creatingvalue.co/sitemap.xml

User-agent: *
Allow: /*

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /images/generic/logo_cva_old.png
```

That file seems to be correct.

Specifically I don't want this image to be present in Google results anymore: https://creatingvalue.co/images/generic/logo_cva_old.png. But it seems that the image is still shown in te results.

## Make sure the new logo is shown as the main logo

I was thinking that perhaps Google had an issue indexing .svg. Although this should be possible shown [in an old blogpost](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/08/google-now-indexes-svg.html), maybe search bots prefer .png's.

So I tried to [add a logo via JSON-LD](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo):

[image]

But still the old logo is shown in the Google result.

---

update 17-07-2020:

I am noticing now that the new logo is added as .svg markup, and not as a file.

Comment: I am currently reading another post (by you) https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51961/how-to-make-google-index-my-website-logo. Will add the markup and will add the logo to the sitemap as suggested.